# MySQL while cycle not working

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop, procedure

I have this code into a procedure:

```
declare counter int unsigned;
declare amount int unsigned;

set counter := 0;
set amount := 3;

while counter <> amount
do
    set counter := counter + 1;
    insert into tablename (column) values (1);
end while;
```

I am expecting this to procude a loop of three inserts, but it generaters five to six inserts instead.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Truncate this table 'tablename' and try again with above code.

Comment: Tried it a couple of times. The behaviour doesn't change.

Comment: i don't know much about MYSQL but are you using proper syntax for set stamenet, i think there should not be : while setting the variable value. Please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried with and without ":" as well, but nothing changed.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you calling it multiple times? Could something else be modifying data in the table in question?